# how can I split output.xml in robot framework

Tags: xml, robotframework

We have a very large output.xml which is more than 400MB when pybot running is done, making it hard to operate.

When I trigger pybot to launch a test, can I split xml to smaller size by pybot command?

The pybot command which I have launch as:

`/usr/local/bin/pybot -v ont_type:G010GP  -v upgrade_delay:300 --outputdir /home/workspace/task_144/G010GP --argumentfile /home/workspace/task_144/G010GP/testcase.txt -e web -e nni -e ping -e telnet -e cvlan4095 -e ssh -e UTU -e NP /repo/root/robot/ATS/GPON_SFU`

Comment: What have you allready considered? Lower logging settings? Rolling up the repeating keywords? Splitsing the tests into separate suites?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean exactly by "hard to operate".

Assuming you're saying it is taking too much disk space, splitting it will not really help. What could help is reducing the amount of logging. I had a project where we would output bunch of stuff, and this really pumps up the filesize of the output, and exponentially.

On the other hand, if you mean that the report/output is too big and makes it hard to read, not enough concise, harder to interpret properly, slow to load in the browser (etc.), you could consider using Robot Framework's submodule [Rebot](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.2/_modules/robot/rebot.html).

The criterion you'll use to split the results are really up to you as you haven't provided much details for this particular matter. Splitting tests by tags is usually the common criteria as it allows you to organize outputs easily.

For example I recently set-up the pipeline for a project that ran a little over 6,000 Robot Framework tests in an agile team. The test suites were tagged with a name identifying the sprint in which they were scripted, and Rebot would split the output/log/report by sprints.